# Socket.EndAccept() error 10054

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

new user to the site here.

I'm working on a simple asynchronous tcp server. My connection listener looks like this.

```
    public static bool Listen(int port)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listener = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            listener.Bind(ep);
            listener.Listen(4);

            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown exception: {0}", e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket listener = (Socket)res.AsyncState;
            Socket inSocket = listener.EndAccept(res);

            Console.WriteLine("Accepted handle: {0}", inSocket.Handle);

            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", se.ErrorCode);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown exception: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally listener.EndAccept(res) triggers a socketexception. It has the error code 10054. The error then keeps occurring for every connection attemp until I restart the listener. What could the problem be?

Also an additional question, what should I set my backlog to?

Comment: Why do you have special catch for the `SocketException`? If you let it fall through into `catch (Exception)` you would see the actual error message and understand better what is going on.

Comment: I made a special cast for SocketException because I wanted the native socket error code. I don't have much coding experience so I figured that a special catch would be the best for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occasional "connection-resets" are legal. Client may have closed the connection before you start to process. Even when you get that error, you have to continue to accept the other requests.
So, `listener.BeginAccept` should be in `finally` block

Comment: Thank you for the quick informative reply. I didn't realize that it wouldn't continue after an exception, I guess my brain is turned off because it's Sunday.